# Filter Javascript array and return only objects that have a populated key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been searching here for a few hours and can't quite find the right answer so far. My apologies if the answer is already out there.

I'm trying to filter an array and return only the objects that have a certain key with any value. Doesn't matter was the value is, just as long as that key is not empty or null.

Array Example:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Song 1",
    "author": "Joe",
    "Album1": 2,
    "Album2": null,
    "Album3": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Song 2",
    "author": "Jane",
    "Album1": null,
    "Album2": null,
    "Album3": 8
  },
  {
    "title": "Song 3",
    "author": "Steve",
    "Album1": 10,
    "Album2": 1,
    "Album3": null
  }
]
```

I'd like to only return the objects that have a value in `Album1` (that value would be the track #). I don't care what the value is, just as long as there's a value. So in this example, only return the following to a new array:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Song 1",
    "author": "Joe",
    "Album1": 2,
    "Album2": null,
    "Album3": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Song 3",
    "author": "Steve",
    "Album1": 10,
    "Album2": null,
    "Album3": null
  }
]
```

I've tried several different methods, each failing. Here's the one that seems like it should work, but doesn't:

```
getFilteredSongs (array, album) {
  return songs
    .filter(function (obj) {
      return Object.keys(album).every(function (a) {
        return obj[a] === true
      })
    })
  }

getFilteredSongs(songsList, Album1)
```

I greatly appreciate any assistance as well as patience with my green skills and inability to find what seems like a question that should be out there.

Comment: what is the value the key takes when there is `no any value`. Is it safe to assume that it will `null` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is return the `Album1` property - if `null`, the resulting array won't be included in the result:

```js
const songs = [
  {
    "title": "Song 1",
    "author": "Joe",
    "Album1": 2,
    "Album2": null,
    "Album3": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Song 2",
    "author": "Jane",
    "Album1": null,
    "Album2": null,
    "Album3": 8
  },
  {
    "title": "Song 3",
    "author": "Steve",
    "Album1": 10,
    "Album2": 1,
    "Album3": null
  }
];

const filtered = songs.filter(({ Album1 }) => Album1);
console.log(filtered);
```

Or, without destructuring, if you prefer:

```
const filtered = songs.filter(song => song.Album1);
```

Or, if you call `getFilteredSongs` with a *string* key of `Album1`:

```js
const songs = [
  {
    "title": "Song 1",
    "author": "Joe",
    "Album1": 2,
    "Album2": null,
    "Album3": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Song 2",
    "author": "Jane",
    "Album1": null,
    "Album2": null,
    "Album3": 8
  },
  {
    "title": "Song 3",
    "author": "Steve",
    "Album1": 10,
    "Album2": 1,
    "Album3": null
  }
];
const getFilteredSongs = (songs, album) => songs.filter(song => song[album]);
console.log(getFilteredSongs(songs, 'Album1'));
```

Comment: Thanks. The second option got me on the path I needed. Much appreciated. Not sure why I couldn't find that in my searches :(.

Answer (score 0):

The following will eliminate any album that has null.

```
filteredSongs = songs.filter((cur) => cur.Album1 !== null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it's possible that `Album1` could be a falsy value other than `undefined`/`null` (such as `0`), you could exclusively check for only `undefined`/`null` as follows:

```js
const songs = [
  {
    "title": "Song 1",
    "author": "Joe",
    "Album1": 2,
    "Album2": null,
    "Album3": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Song 2",
    "author": "Jane",
    "Album1": null,
    "Album2": null,
    "Album3": 8
  },
  {
    "title": "Song 3",
    "author": "Steve",
    "Album1": 10,
    "Album2": 1,
    "Album3": null
  }
];

const filteredSongs = songs.filter(({Album1}) => Album1 != null); // filters out only undefined/null
console.log(filteredSongs);
```